# How to save data into the User's Application Support?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I want to save some XML formatted data into the Application Support folder, but I have no idea how to do that.

Does anyone know any tutorials for teaching you how to save data into the Application Support folder and how to create an XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the kind of data, the simplest is to [write an NSDictionary to plist format.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToURL%3aatomically%3a) If it's not and can't be an NSDictionary, look at [NSXMLDocument.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLDocument/XMLData)

Application Support folder is best located using [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains)

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I found this website that really did help my problem.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/281310-creating-an-application-support-folder.html