# Saving an NSDictionary to File, and Creating a New File

Tags: objective-c, file, nsdictionary

I'm trying to discover a way to save an NSDictionary, (which will probably hold high scores and users on a particular system.) onto a new file. I would like to know how to create the file, and put it in the location that it should be, preferably where it can't be touched by the user. Is there any place that these kinds of files are meant to be?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `NSDictionary`? You should see a method for saving the dictionary to a file. Then do some searching on how to save a file to the Documents folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

Either make Plist of your NSDictionary and write to Documents Directory

OR

Make JSON string >> Convert it to NSData using NSJSONSerialization >> Write it to Documents Directory

You can write files in documents directory using NSFileManager

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question:

[How to save data into the User's Application Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210672/how-to-save-data-into-the-users-application-support)

The best place to save such files is the "Application Support" folder in the users "Library" folder. The user could go there, but most users won't.

The first answer also has a link on how to save an NSDictionary to a file.

**Edit**

My answer applies for osx applications only. If you making an app for ios, you should save your file to your app's "Documents" directory.